# How to write a javascript condition if someone clicks on a url that contains hashtag at the end

Tags: javascript

How to fire a javascript condition on a webpage if a visitor clicks on a url that contains hashtag at the end. For example like if I click on an anchor tag i.e. abc.com/page.html# then condition runs and return true.

I tried to do the following

```
if (document.querySelector("a[hash='"+hashValue+"']").click() ) 
// do something;
```

but its not working. Any clue?

Comment: What do you want to `return true` to? The caller of the event listener? (sounds a bit strange, that wouldn't do anything)

Comment: So the hash needs to be last character or just contained in the url?

Comment: hash needs to be the last character @nick

Comment: i just want to execute a function  that do something if i click on a url that contains hashtag at the end here for example i put return true

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to the window (document, body, or any other element that contains all the links will also work), check if the element is an anchor and use `String#endsWith` on its `href`.

```js
addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target instanceof HTMLAnchorElement && event.target.href.endsWith("#")) {
    console.log("Hash");
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="about:blank" target="_blank">Test without #</a>
<a href="about:blank#test" target="_blank">Test with #</a>
<a href="about:blank#" target="_blank">Test with hash at end#</a>
<button>Invalid Button 1</button>
<button href="about:blank#">Invalid Button 2</button>
```

You could also add an event listener to every anchor element that ends with `#` (will only work if you will not dynamically add more links to the page):

```js
function onAnchorClick(event) {
  console.log("Hash");
}

for (var anchor of document.querySelectorAll("a[href$='#']")) {
  anchor.addEventListener("click", onAnchorClick);
}
```

```html
<a href="about:blank" target="_blank">Test without #</a>
<a href="about:blank#test" target="_blank">Test with #</a>
<a href="about:blank#" target="_blank">Test with hash at end#</a>
<button>Invalid Button 1</button>
<button href="about:blank#">Invalid Button 2</button>
```

Here are some notes on how to select items containing certain properties:

- property is equal to `[propertyName="fullPropertyValue"]`
- property is not equal to `:not([propertyName="fullPropertyValue"])`
- property starts with `[propertyName^="startValue"]`
- property doesn't start with `:not([propertyName^="startValue"])`
- property contains `[propertyName*="partValue"]`
- property doesn't contain `:not([propertyName*="partValue"])`
- property ends with `[propertyName$="endValue"]`
- property doesn't end with `:not([propertyName$="endValue"])`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `href` not `hash` and attach event listener to it

```
document.querySelector("a[href='"+hashValue+"']").addEventListener('click',(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    //Do some thing here
})
```

Or better to use Template Strings to avoid problems

```
document.querySelector(`a[href="${hashValue}"']`).addEventListener('click',(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        //Do some thing here 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```js
function findUrl(obj) {
 var url = obj.getAttribute("href");
 var retVal = url.endsWith("#");
 console.log(retVal);
 return retVal;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com/#" id="link" onclick="findUrl(this); return false;">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Regular Expression with following pattern :

[#]$

```js
 var str1 = "http://google.com/#"; 
        var str2 = "http://google.com/#/dfdjh"; 
        console.log(' str 1 outcome : '+str1.search('[\#]$'));
        console.log(' str 2 outcome : '+str2.search('[\#]$'));
```

Outcome is position of # if string matches the regex pattern.
So in first case, position is a positive number and -1 in case when condition does not matches.